# sed command not working in mac

Tags: bash, sed

Following sed command is not working on my lion mac.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/user_dashboard/user/g' {} \;
```

I am getting this error

```
sed: 1: "./vendor/assets/javascr ...": invalid command code .
```

Comment: if you're doing this on OSx, you need to use `sed -i ""` to rename your file in-place. Good luck.

Comment: `-i` as you're using it is a GNU `sed` feature.

Comment: @shellter: That's correct; you should submit it as an answer, so you can get credit for it.

Answer (score 25):

The OSX version of `sed` is not the same as those found in most Linux systems.

It extends the `-i`  option to give you the opportunity save a file with a different extension, but requires input for that extension.

If you just want to overwrite the file in place, you need to use `sed -i "" ...sedCmd.... fileName` to rename your file in-place.

Per @JamesMcMahon 's comment, see here for the [full doc for OSX/BSD sed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sed.1.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This answer deserves to be flagged as answer!

Answer (score 6):

`-i` probably has a different meaning (not "in-place") in your version of sed. Try using `gsed` if available or replacing `-i` with `-e` and using a temporary file (and a `mv` afterwards) to emulate it.

Comment: Easy way to install gsed on mac is through [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/).

Comment: Or with MacPorts: ```sudo port install gsed```

Answer (score 3):

replacing text inside a file on the fly with sed on mac is possible,

the command is just a little different.

with: `-i`    , you have to specify a postfix, which sed will use to save the original file after it modified it.

run the command as:

```
$ sed -i _backup -E 's/foo/bar/' /tmp/jestinkt.txt
```

ending with both the modified /tmp/jestinkt.txt and the original /tmp/jestinkt.txt_backup