# Why does sed have different behavior depending on input method?

Tags: macos, sed, backreference

On Mac OS 10.9, I have a file, test.txt:

```
_static
_images
```

running the command

`cat test.txt | sed -E -e "s/(_static|_images)/foo\1/g"`

has the expected output of

```
foo_static
foo_images
```

but running the command to edit the file in place:

`sed -i -E -e "s/(_static|_images)/foo\1/g" test.txt`

gives me

`sed: 1: "s/(_static|_images)/foo ...": \1 not defined in the RE`

I need to use the second method but it complains of the backreference not being there. It works in the first method so I'm scratching my head as to what I'm supposed to do differently.

Comment: strange! a workaround can be `sed ... file > temp & mv temp file`

Comment: The issue is with `sed` misinterpreting the options passed to it. The `-i ext` means modify the file and make a backup with extension `ext`. In your case the extension is `-E`. Now sed assumes you are running a basic regex because you didn't pass `-E` option. Try `sed -i '' -E -e "s/(_static|_images)/foo\1/g" test.txt`

Comment: @alvits is correct, since OS X uses the BSD version of `sed` instead of the GNU version. See shellter's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744300/sed-command-not-working-in-mac/9750006#9750006).

Comment: Thank you. You guys got it right.